# Sitefinity dynamic module field custom validation

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-dynamic-content-types

I have dynamic module with a textbox field "Priority" in the backend edit page that I want to validate. However, I want to validate it against all other db entries of the same field to ensure that only one of them has this textbox value, If one of them already has this value, I want the backend to refuse the submission and display validation error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGzqS.png)

i can check value using following events and validate against database when user is editing backend form
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-dynamic-modules-events

Is it possible to add a custom validator to a dynamic module content type field? how do we show error message on backend screen after validation is done throgh code behind.

Im using Sitefinity 10.2

Comment: I believe if you throw an exception in one of these events (IDynamicContentUpdatingEvent) then the message will be shown as an alert on the page and item won't be published.